# Adding permmisions to a custom formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I've made a custom formula to search my Gmail account for specific emails and return the mail subject line.

when I ran it manually it worked fine but then I've changed it to run as a google sheets formula and I've received the following error:

> Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action.
> Required permissions: (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify || https://mail.google.com/`) (line 35).

the function:

```
function LASTEMAILFROM(userInput){
  //var userInput = "@fashionnova.com"//this is commented out because it should be enterd by the user
  var userInputReady = `from:` + userInput  ;
  var message = GmailApp.search(userInputReady)[0].getMessages()[0].getThread();

  var output = message.getFirstMessageSubject();
  return output;}
```

I have entered these permissions in appsscript.json in the following form:

```
{"oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata",
      "https://mail.google.com/"
    ], ... }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's not possible.

Comment: They are called custom functions.